# DAX - Lookup value to retrieve exchange rate

Tags: dax

In table "Paypal", I have:

[image]

And in table "Câmbios":

[image]

And now, I'm adding a calculated column to "Paypal" table with the formula:

```
Câmbio = LOOKUPVALUE('Câmbios'[Câmbio];'Câmbios'[Mês];MONTH('Paypal'[Date]))
```

Which is returning the error:

```
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.
```

This doesn't make sense to me.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `Câmbios` table contains repeated values for at least one month and the `LOOKUPVALUE` function doesn't know which value use to retrieve the specified column.

You can use instead:

```
Cambio =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Cambio[Cambio] ),
    FILTER ( Cambio, [Mes] = MONTH ( EARLIER ( Paypal[Date] ) ) )
)
```

Or delete the repeated values from `Cambios[Mes]`.

Comment: I knew it had to be obvious